# Hibernate @Formula working for Postgres JSONB field using the Criteria API, but H2 Tests causing syntax error

Tags: postgresql, jpa, h2, jsonb, criteria-api

I have a very invovled query using the Criteria API and a requirement to sort it on a field in a JSONB column on my table which works perfectly well. Here is my field as it's declared in my Entity class:

```java
@Formula(value = "(metadata->>'pendingReassignment')::boolean")  
private Boolean pendingReassignment;
```

The problem is I have is it's breaking my tests again my H2 database. I have this statement in my initialization scripts which has worked for testing the entities with JSONB columns:

```
CREATE domain IF NOT EXISTS jsonb AS other;
```

But my function translates the H2 SQL to `(COMPARISON0_.METADATA - [*] >> 'pendingReassignment')::boolean` which causes a syntax error.

Any ideas how to work around it would be appreciated.

Comment: H2 simply does not support JSON the way Postgres does, e.g. it does not support any of the JSON operator and functions including the `->>` operator (and probably neither the cast operator `::`) https://phauer.com/2017/dont-use-in-memory-databases-tests-h2/

Comment: I understand that, I was just hoping for a workaround without having to just remove the conflicting tests. For example, I add this statement to my initialization scripts to actually have JSON columns in my entities without having H2 blow up: CREATE domain IF NOT EXISTS jsonb AS other;